# How to get a child control from a Tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden field in each `Tr` in my template:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="" class="ui-selectee trClass ui-widget-content">
        <td style="width: 100px">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="idField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

No, in the `each` loop on the selected `Tr`, how can I get the hidden field ?

```
$(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
    var index = $(".selectable tr").index(this);

    var idField = ??
});
```

I've already started with:

```
var idField = $(".selectable tr > [id*='idField']");
```

But seems it does not work!

Any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id = $('tr.ui-selectee td input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

Comment: Thnaks, but I prefer dealing with ID of the control instead of its type

Comment: @Jack, the ID could be mangled by ASP.NET so it would be better to work with either a class selector or a type.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: But it's a hidden field and seems it does not support classes.

Comment: @Jack, of course that it supports classes. Hidden fields render as `<input type="hidden" class="foo" name="foo" value="bar" />`.

Comment: @Darin: I've tried it, the following error has been raised: `Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' does not have a public property named 'CssClass'. `

Comment: @Darin: sorry, I'll use HTML control instead. Thanks alot

Comment: @Jack, isn't the following working: `<input type="hidden" value="<%# Eval("Id") %>" runat="server" class="someClass" />`?

Comment: @Darin: It worked find, thank you very much. It just need HTML control instead of ASP.Net Hidden Field.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('#idField').val();// use common class for hidden field,that would be good.

    alert(index );
});
```

Comment: Can I use classes with Hidden Fields ?